# Leaflet photo plugins library compatiblity issue

Tags: leaflet, photos

I am using the Leaflet photos plugin, it runs perfectly using the Leaflet v0.7.7
but using the newest version of Leaflet v1.4.0
it doesn't work and it gives the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined
    at h (leaflet.js:5)
    at u (leaflet.js:5)
    at e.on (leaflet.js:5)
    at e.initialize (leaflet.markercluster.js:6)
    at e.initialize (Leaflet.Photo.js:63)
    at new e (leaflet.js:5)
    at Function.L.photo.cluster (Leaflet.Photo.js:80)
    at index.html:65
```

the web map code is the following

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([35.924629,5.301136], 14);

var Base =L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.dartotalsolutions.com">DAR TOTAL SOLUTIONS</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
var photos = [{
"lat":35.927689,"lng": 5.31083,"name":"","url":"jpg/20170227_084620.jpg","thumbnail":"thumbnail/20170227_084620.jpg"},{
"lat":35.927689,"lng": 5.31083,"name":"","url":"jpg/20170227_084637.jpg","thumbnail":"thumbnail/20170227_084637.jpg"},{
"lat":35.927689,"lng": 5.31083,"name":"","url":"jpg/20170227_084639.jpg","thumbnail":"thumbnail/20170227_084639.jpg"}];
var photoLayer = L.photo.cluster().on('click', function(evt) {
  var photo = evt.layer.photo;
  var template = '<img src="{url}" /></a><p>{name}</p>';
  evt.layer.bindPopup(L.Util.template(template, photo), {
    className: 'leaflet-popup-photo',
    minWidth: 800
  }).openPopup();
});
photoLayer.add(photos).addTo(map);
L.control.layers({
'OSM' :Base,
},{
'Photos':photoLayer,
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: I had no problem running your example with the latest versions of Leaflet library and MarkerCluster and Leaflet Photo plugins.

Comment: The problem is in your  MarkerCluster compatibility, not in Leaflet Photo plugins, the following MarkerCluster works fine here the js & css https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.3.0/dist/leaflet.markercluster.js  https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.3.0/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css  https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.3.0/dist/MarkerCluster.css